# Google Docs API - Can you ask it to zip several files before download to a PC

Tags: c#-3.0, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a WinForms application in C# and I want to download several files as a single Zip file to speed the download. How can I use the API to do this?

Also, is it faster / more efficient to start several threads to download several files or 1 thread to download files in sequence?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it directly in Docs API - java example [here](http://snoopconsultingrd.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-download-multiple-files-as-one.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what you are asking for but as I understand your problem you it could be solved by simply picking up the files from the API and use the zip function in Python to zip them together. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583791/is-it-possible-to-generate-and-return-a-zip-file-with-app-engine)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it does address the problem, the issue is I am not familiar with Python :( - But thanks anyway.