# How to download all objects in single zip file in Google Cloud storage using Python GCS JSON API

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage

I have some objects in different path in one bucket of Google Cloud storage.

I want to download all files in single zip file.

I am using Python GCS JSON API.

Comment: how many files? and how big are they?

Comment: Thanks,  It is approximately 5mb.

Answer (score 2):

This gcs_zip_dynamics() function shows you [here](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133) how to zip GCS files.

To download you can use:

```
self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = b'multipart/x-zip'
self.response.headers[b'Content-Disposition'] = str('attachment; filename=<file_name>.zip'
self.response.write(gcs_data.gcs_read_blob(dyn))
```

The gcs_read_blob() function is also part of the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133).

Answer (score 1):

- Use the [cloudstorage library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) to download the files.
- Use the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) library to create your zip archive.
- Add the downloaded files to the zip archive.
- Serve your zip file to the client.

Great example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583791/is-it-possible-to-generate-and-return-a-zip-file-with-app-engine).